# Render {Caption} within {block:Photos} on Tumblr

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr

There seems to be a bit of a problem with tumblr in that you can't render `{Caption}` tags if it's within a `{block:Photos}` tag. The problem is that the way my theme works calls for it to be done in that way.

```
{block:Photoset}
    <div class="object photo">
        {block:Photos}
            <a href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="fancybox" rel="{PostID}" title="{Caption}"><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" /></a>
        {/block:Photos}
    </div>
{/block:Photoset}
```

The reason for this is that I'm using [FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to add a caption to each of the photos in the set which you have to do by adding a title to the `title` attribute.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the caption in the caption block? `{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}`

Comment: Yeah but that didn't work unfortunately. I think it might be a job for JavaScript to be honest but it goes a bit beyond my basic knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The example in their docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photoset-posts) does exactly that, a {Caption} inside {block:Photos}. In that block, {Caption} refers to the single photo's caption.

I'm guessing that you want the photoset's caption, not the single photo's. In your case that caption is likely empty, so you're not seeing anything.

I don't think it can be done via template, so here's a quick fix using jQuery:

```
$('.photoset[data-caption]').each(function () {//select photosets that have a caption
  var caption = $(this).data('caption');//get stored caption
  $(this).find('.fancybox')//find link that needs the caption
    .attr( 'title', caption );//add caption to link
});
```

And here's the template:

```
{block:Photoset}
  <div class="object photoset" {block:Caption}data-caption="{PlaintextCaption}"{/block:Caption}> <!-- Note the > after the block caption -->
    {block:Photos}
      <a href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="fancybox" rel="{PostID}"><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" /></a>
    {/block:Photos}
  </div>
{/block:Photoset}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. For some reason it's not attributing the 'title' to the posts though. The data-caption bit is working fine but it's not adding the title at all.

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry. `title` required quotes in the javascript. I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

or you can just, put the **{block:caption}{caption}{/block:caption}** below the **{/block:photos}**, not inside it, had the same issue and this worked for me.